# Change Pivot table Cache code not working

Tags: excel, pivot

I'm trying to change the pivot cache to the actual pivot table itself. I've filtered the data in a way I like and cant let other people see the unfiltered data and as such I'm using the filtered table as a new source data.

I've got most of the code working but I'm not sure why the below code isn't working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim pts     As PivotTables
Dim pt      As PivotTable
Dim pf      As PivotField
Dim ptRng   As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pts = ActiveSheet.PivotTables
If pts.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
pt.Name = ws.Name

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name).ChangePivotCache _
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pt.DataBodyRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name).PivotFields("Row Labels")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    pt.Name).PivotFields("Count of Option Name3"), _
    "Sum of Count of Option Name3", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    pt.Name).PivotFields("Count of Option Name3"), _
    "Sum of Count of Option Name3_2", xlSum
Range("C4").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name).PivotFields( _
    "Sum of Count of Option Name3_2")
    .Calculation = xlPercentOfColumn
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name).PivotFields("Row Labels")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
```

Comment: Try SourceData:=pt.DataBodyRange

Comment: When I try that it breaks the rest of the code and it doesn't include the row names

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood. AFAIK the Create method requires a same arranged table as the original one with only the visible rows, which then to Add to the PivotTables and then set programatically the  necessary rows,columns and other parameters of it. That's how i would do it.

Comment: This is another workaround, Lock only the cells of the PivotTable and turn on Sheet protection. After it you cannot select the table and click on it.